# MySQL cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails with FK between multiple databases

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two databases and am trying to link tables from each database together but am running into some issues.

Here is the table creation in database A:

```
CREATE TABLE Process(pro_id          INT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                     name           TEXT NOT NULL,
                                     reactant_id     INT NOT NULL,
                                     saddle_id       INT NOT NULL,
                                     product_id      INT NOT NULL,
                                     FOREIGN KEY(reactant_id) REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id),
                                     FOREIGN KEY(saddle_id)   REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id),
                                     FOREIGN KEY(product_id)  REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id));
```

here is the table creatinon in database B:

```
CREATE TABLE Process(pro_id          INT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                     name           TEXT NOT NULL,
                     original_pro_id INT NOT NULL,
                     reactant_id     INT NOT NULL,
                     saddle_id       INT NOT NULL,
                     product_id      INT NOT NULL,
                     FOREIGN KEY(reactant_id)     REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id),
                     FOREIGN KEY(saddle_id)       REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id),
                     FOREIGN KEY(product_id)      REFERENCES Atoms(atoms_id))

ALTER TABLE Process
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_name(original_pro_id) REFERENCES A.Process(pro_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

When I do my inserts. I insert into A.Process, commit, change databases, insert into B.Process and that is when I get the error.

Comment: I assume there is an `Atoms` table in both schemas?

Comment: Correct. I could add them but I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: All `Atoms` records referenced are definitely in both schemas? Do you get a specific error?

Comment: I am quite sure. if I remove the original_pro_id field from B.Process I have no issues inserting in either database. The full error is this
    'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kdb`.`Process`, CONSTRAINT `Process_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`original_pro_id`) REFERENCES `kdb_backup`.`Process` (`pro_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)')

where database A = kdb_backup and database B = kdb

Comment: Well, my only other guess is perhaps try using a name other than `process`... and just to cover all bases, the schemas are on the same server, right?

Comment: changing the name didn't fix it. However after re reading your previous comment. When you say "All Atoms records referenced are definitely in both schemas?" Do you mean I should reference A.Atoms in database B and vise-versa? If so I don't do this and do not know how. I simply have a A.Atoms and B.Atoms tables.

Comment: I was just making sure you were synching the atoms table across the schemas; otherwise you could end up with the A.Process record referencing atoms not mirrored in the B schema's atoms table...which would cause a problem when mirroring the record to B's Process table.